# Hex IP to Decimal IP conversion

Tags: c

How can I convert a hex ip (such as `42477f35`), and get it to spit out the correct decimal ip (in the example before, the correct result is `66.71.127.53`)?

I'd like it to take the hex ip in as a string, then output the correct result as a string too so I can use it elsewhere in the C code.

I'm not an expert in C, so if any of you can help me out, it'd be appreciated.

Comment: Systematically throwing the ball back at the asker with this canned sentence isn't really helping anyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one possibility:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ip_hex_to_dquad(const char *input, char *output, size_t outlen)
{
    unsigned int a, b, c, d;

    if (sscanf(input, "%2x%2x%2x%2x", &a, &b, &c, &d) != 4)
        return -1;

    snprintf(output, outlen, "%u.%u.%u.%u", a, b, c, d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks promising.  I'll test this, and get back to you.

Comment: Shouldnt this `snprintf(output, outlen, "%u.%u.%u.%u", a, b, c, d);` be like this `snprintf(output, outlen, "%u.%u.%u.%u", d, c, b, a);` since the IP is in reverse order?

Comment: @kuchi: In this question the hexadecimal and decimal versions of the IP are in the same order - see the OP's example.  If you are seeing a "reversed" IP then you are probably directly printing a network-byte-order value on a little-endian architecture.

Answer (score 3):

You could use sscanf to pick the hexadecimal out of the original string as integers and then use sprintf to put them into another string in the proper format.

```
sscanf(hexipstring, "%2x%2x%2x%2x", &uint0, &uint1, &uint2, &uint3);
sprintf("%u.%u.%u.%u", uint0, uint1, uint2, uint3);
```

Or something like that.  i'm never really sure with scanf, so read through some man pages.  The "%2x" should tell scanf to use 2 characters at most and interpret them as a hexadecimal number.

-edit: Caf's code is better since it checks for errors in sscanf and uses snprintf rather than sprintf.  More errorproof.  Use it instead of mine.

Answer (score -1):

Split the hex ip into octets (two hex digits at a time), and convert each octet to a decimal integer.

Comment: Downvoting because i considered that, but dont know about the hex-to-decimal conversion part